Is it necessary to connect the (-) terminal to earth when connecting two bench top power supplies in series to achieve a bipolar supply?
I have noticed when researching online that it is always mentioned to connect the (-) terminal to earth when connecting two power supplies in series to create a bipolar supply. Is there any issue with not earth referencing the 0V rail? I would rather have a floating bipolar supply.
I have tested with my supply and it seems to work but I can't be sure I'm not missing something as I don't know why there is an earth terminal since the voltages from a bench PSU are low enough to not need safety earth.

This question is a gray area but a good question. Does the manual say anything about this?

I'm using a Tenma (Korad) PSU and the manual doesn't mention anything about it.

I should have been more clear, only the negative terminal of the first supply or the positive of the second supply are connected to earth ground as they are shorted together to create the series connection. The positive terminal of the first supply is +V, the negative of the first supply and the positive of the second is 0V and the negative of the second is -V.

If you connect two power supplies in series to create a bipolar supply, you connect the positive terminal of one supply to the negative terminal of the other, and call that point "Zero Volts".  Whether you connect that point to Earth/Safety Ground or not is up to you and to the requirements of whatever is using the bipolar supply.
Note that we generally call the Zero Volt point of a circuit "Ground", and even put a Ground symbol on it.  This (mis)use of the term "Ground" does not necessarily imply any connection to The Earth/Safety Ground.
The Earth terminal on many power supplies is there for convenience, in case the user does want to connect their circuit to Earth.

Thanks for your input! It gives me some peace of mind before connecting an oscilloscope to the circuit if I don't have to worry about shorting to mains earth through scope probe.

No it is not mandatory.
You can choose to leave the earth terminal disconnected for floating supply, or you can choose to connect it for earth-referenced supply.
However, always do what power supply manuals say. If they say you must earth one supply, then that's what you must do, and it may be difficult to figure out why it needs to be done.

The manual is unfortunately in broken English (https://www.nikom.biz/pdf/KORAD_power.pdf) but it doesn't mention anything about earth in the section on series mode so I assume it's designed to work without the earth connection. My testing seems to show it works but I just wanted to learn a bit more before connecting a scope to the 0V. Next I will test the continuity of the supply to mains earth to make sure it's floating as the manual says some funny stuff about shielding.

"Press the button SER/INDEP for over 2 seconds to enter
series mode and then the indicator SER lights on. In the
output of series mode, CH2 is the main control, where
operation will be finished while CH1 will be shielded."

@Pernel_Sned It sounds like when you put a dual channel unit into series mode, it uses one set of controls and the other set of controls is locked/protected(/guarded/shielded) so you can't use the controls accidentally. It has nothing to do with earthing/grounding.

ok, that makes sense as that's exactly what happens
